# Como fazer uma condição com os operadores "+", "-", "*","/"

Tags: string, perl

Eu tenho o seguinte código:

```
print ("Primeiro Valor: ");
$valor1 = <STDIN>;
print ("Segundo Valor: ");
$valor2 = <STDIN>;
print ("Operador: ");
$op = <STDIN>;
if ($op == "+")
{
    $total = $valor1 + $valor2;
    print ($total);
}

elsif ($op == "-")
{
    $total = $valor1 - $valor2;
    print ($total);
}

elsif ($op== "*")
{
    $total = $valor1 * $valor2;
    print ($total);
}

elsif ($op == "/")
{
    $total = $valor1 / $valor2;
    print ($total);
}
```

Ele lê tudo correctamente mas quando entra na condição do `if` se o utilizador inserir `"-"`, `"/"` ou `"*"` ele entra sempre na primeira condição e faz uma soma e queria tentar perceber o porquê.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Em Perl, strings devem ser comparadas com o operador `eq`:

```
if ($op eq "+")
{
    $total = $valor1 + $valor2;
    print ($total);
}
elsif ($op eq "-")
{
    $total = $valor1 - $valor2;
    print ($total);
}
elsif ($op eq "*")
{
    $total = $valor1 * $valor2;
    print ($total);
}
elsif ($op eq "/")
{
    $total = $valor1 / $valor2;
    print ($total);
}
```

Você também deve chamar `chomp` para remover a quebra de linha (introduzida quando você digita o <kbd>ENTER</kbd>), logo depois de ler o dado:

```
$op = <STDIN>;
chomp($op);

if ($op eq "+") etc...
```

---

Quando você usa `==`, é feita uma comparação numérica. E as strings `"+"`, `"-"`, `"*"` e `"/"`, ao serem convertidas para número, [resultam em zero](https://perlmaven.com/automatic-value-conversion-or-casting-in-perl). Por isso o primeiro `if` sempre será verdadeiro, pois ambas as strings se tornam o valor numérico zero.

Comment: Entendi agora o que tinha feito de mal, a sua explicação ajudou muito a compreender. A minha experiência anterior de programação era C# e Python e tenho agora começado Perl com uns exercícios e não estava mesmo a conseguir resolver este, mas compreendi o que estava de mal.